# Ability to run gcloud commands from a container in GKE or CloudRun

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-iam

I have just installed `gcloud` on a docker container.

When I try to run a command locally, I get the following error (which makes sense)

```
root@3c4b9a147de7:/# gcloud projects list
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.list) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
different account:

  $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

If I set appropriately the service account (to the service which the container will run from) will the above command work?

Answer (score 2):

> If I set appropriately the service account (to the service which the
>   container will run from) will the above command work?

I am not sure what you mean by "to the service which the container will run from". The service might have credentials assigned to it, but anything inside the container will not know this.

To use a service account with the Google Cloud SDK CLI, you need to configure the CLI to use the service account. The following command does this. Replace SA_EMAIL with your service account's email address. The email address can be found inside the service account JSON key file.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account SA_EMAIL --key-file=service_account.json
```

After you run this command save the container so that the credentials will still be there the next time you launch this container.

Comment: I mean for example if I run the container from CloudRun, and I assign to CloudRun a GCP IAM Service Account with say the permissions corresponding to the invocation of `gcloud projects list`, then the command will be able to execute from within the container running via CloudRun?

Comment: 1/2) My answer was for this statement: "When I try to run a command locally, I get the following error (which makes sense)" which will also work when you deploy the container.

Comment: 2/2) I cannot answer if the Cloud Run metadata server works with the CLI inside Cloud Run as I have never tried it. The metadata server handles your service account credentials inside compute services (Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, Compute Engine, ...). When Google sets up the CLI in Compute Engine image builds, I am not sure if they do anything special so that `gcloud` is correctly configured for accessing the metadata server. Normally the CLI stores its configuration relative to the user's home directory. You don't have a home directory in Cloud Run.

Answer (score 0):

If the docker container has gcloud sdk installed ([google cloud SDK Shell](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/?hl=es)) ,  run the google Cloud SDK to authenticate using `$ gcloud auth login` after this you can run gcloud command line.   check as well the path in Enviroments variable for the gcloud directory

Answer (score 0):

`gcloud auth login` is not recommended in container because it references your identity. Prefer a service account. Store it in your container and define the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL` to point to this file.

You can also run a `gcloud auth activate-service-account` with your service account file in param during your container build.

**HOWEVER**, it's not recommended to use this tool in container. With Cloud Run, it's even possible that this call will be blocked (I never try, but take care of the sandbox environment execution). Prefer the libs or the direct call to API.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, yes it's failing because the root account that you are using is running locally as you say so it doesn't have any permissions regarding your project.

When something is run through Cloud Run, then it's using by default the Compute Engine service account. If that account has the permissions needed, then the command will succeed. Take a look about authentication in Cloud Build [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity) Something similar would apply for GKE regarding the service account as you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform).